# To Find Lowest Common Ancestor in a Tree[Binary] but with multiple Node IN python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

To find the lowest ancestor of a tree tried the below code.

```
# A binary tree node 
class Node: 
    # Constructor to create a new binary node 
    def __init__(self, key): 
        self.key =  key 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

# Finds the path from root node to given root of the tree. 
# Stores the path in a list path[], returns true if path  
# exists otherwise false 
def findPath( root, path, k): 

    # Baes Case 
    if root is None: 
        return False

    # Store this node is path vector. The node will be 
    # removed if not in path from root to k 
    path.append(root.key) 

    # See if the k is same as root's key 
    if root.key == k : 
        return True

    # Check if k is found in left or right sub-tree 
    if ((root.left != None and findPath(root.left, path, k)) or
            (root.right!= None and findPath(root.right, path, k))): 
        return True 

    # If not present in subtree rooted with root, remove 
    # root from path and return False 

    path.pop() 
    return False

# Returns LCA if node n1 , n2 are present in the given 
# binary tre otherwise return -1 
def findLCA(root, n1, n2): 

    # To store paths to n1 and n2 fromthe root 
    path1 = [] 
    path2 = [] 

    # Find paths from root to n1 and root to n2. 
    # If either n1 or n2 is not present , return -1  
    if (not findPath(root, path1, n1) or not findPath(root, path2, n2)): 
        return -1 

    # Compare the paths to get the first different value 
    i = 0 
    while(i < len(path1) and i < len(path2)): 
        if path1[i] != path2[i]: 
            break
        i += 1
    return path1[i-1] 


root = Node(0) 
root.left = Node(1) 
root.right = Node(2) 
root.left.left = Node(3) 
root.left.right = Node(4)
root.right.left = Node(5) 
root.right.right = Node(6) 
root.right.right = Node(11) 
root.left.right.left = Node(7)
root.left.right.right = Node(8)
root.right.left.left = Node(9) 
root.right.left.left.left = Node(10) 


print "LCA(3, 8) = %d" %(findLCA(root, 3, 8,)) 
print "LCA(1, 8) = %d" %(findLCA(root, 1, 8)) 
print "LCA(8, 6) = %d" %(findLCA(root,8,6)) 
print "LCA(10, 2) = %d" %(findLCA(root,10, 2)) 
print "LCA(7, 6) = %d" %(findLCA(root,7, 6)) 
print "LCA(0, 9) = %d" %(findLCA(root,0, 9)) 
print "LCA(10, 11) = %d" %(findLCA(root,10,11)) 
print "LCA(11, 3) = %d" %(findLCA(root,11,3))
```

But have a scenario where in have multiple nodes connected to the same node, in that case the program errors out which make sense because of the left, right node.

[image]

```
OUtput:
LCA(3, 8) = 1
LCA(1, 8) = 1
LCA(8, 6) = -1
LCA(10, 2) = 2
LCA(7, 6) = -1
LCA(0, 9) = 0
LCA(10, 11) = 2
LCA(11, 3) = 0
```

Any way i can overcome with multiple nodes to the same node ? Kindly provide your comments.

Comment: If your tree is binary, by definition, one node cannot have three children. If you want an n-ary tree, use an array for the children and call it a general "tree", not a "binary tree".

Comment: Your problem is that node 6 doesn't exist after you replace it with node 11.  Your tree is binary so there can be only one root.right.right.  After you assign a value of 11 to this, 6 is no longer mapped in your tree.  In your drawing you show 3 children of node 2 - but your binary tree structure can have (definitionally) only two children.

Comment: @joanis: Is there any already existing algorithms which takes an array of nodes to a particular node ? and still provide the LCA ?

Comment: @T3am5hark: Ahh.. True.. Its not a binary tree [but more or less like it], but my scenario is like to have multiple nodes to a single node and still to get the LCA of the same.

Comment: @Vimo as coded, it is a binary tree.  If you want a non-binary tree with the ability to have >2 children, you need a different node mapping (e.g. a list to accommodate multiple child nodes).  But then you can't use the left/right navigation approach in findPath and have to change the code in the recursion.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below method . What it does is , it will keep traversing the tree recursively , until the path for the nodes separates . And it return the node itself .

```
def lca(root, v1, v2):
if (v1>root.info) and (v2>root.info):
    res = lca(root.right,v1,v2)
elif (v1<root.info) and (v2<root.info):
    res = lca(root.left,v1,v2)
else:
    res = root
return res
```